# Email Markup Tester

Tags: json, email, markup, schema.org

Google's email Markup Tester always fails with the error

"INVALID_OBJECT: orderStatus,http://schema.org/OrderStatusType"

I have tried with all there samples located on this page:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order

Do we think its just a question of waiting for them to fix it?

example json:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Order",
  "merchant": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Amazon.com"
  },
  "orderNumber": "123-4567890-1234567",
  "priceCurrency": "USD",
  "price": "29.99",
  "acceptedOffer": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "itemOffered": {
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Google Chromecast"
    },
    "price": "29.99",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "eligibleQuantity": {
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
      "value": "1"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://www.amazon.ca/gp/css/summary/edit.html/orderID=123-4567890-1234567"
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed validation by adding:

```
"orderStatus" : "OrderDelivered",
```

I noticed using the following **didn't work** (even though it is how the Google Example [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order) has it ):

```
"orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderStatus/OrderDelivered",
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google is insisting that you provide a valid statusOrder key. The the following validates:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Order",
          "merchant": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Amazon.com"
          },
          "orderNumber": "123-4567890-1234567",
          "priceCurrency": "USD",
          "price": "29.99",
          "acceptedOffer": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Product",
              "name": "Google Chromecast"
            },
            "price": "29.99",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "eligibleQuantity": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "value": "1"
            }
        },
             "orderStatus" : "OrderDelivered",
             "url": "https://www.amazon.ca/gp/css/summary/edit.html/orderID=123-4567890-1234567"

        }
        </script>
```